# UITextView not showing globe icon in keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uitextview

I am using third party library UIGrowingTextView for chat application purpose and I need to support Arabic and English to be typed in UITextView. But when I open the keyboard it does not show globe icon button on keyboard and **I am not able to paste Arabic text in it.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue once, what worked for me is to check storyboard.

If keyboard type is ASCII Capable then globe icon will not show there, so keep it default. Check below screenshot.

[image]

After doing this changes, if you are still not able to write/paste arabic text then look into your code and see following method.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    return text.canBeConverted(to: .ascii)
}
```

Hope this helped you.